# Multiprocessing: Passing (and iterating) a list of arrays to pool map

Tags: python, list, dictionary, multiprocessing, pool

I've been playing around with passing strings into a function.

As an example, with input_list_1, I find the return from the function partially correct - only the first n which matches the number of processors are correct. The remaining outputs are incorrect. I experimented with the chunksize input and with map_async but no luck.

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
input_list_1=['string1','string2','string3','string4']
results=pool.map(somefunction, input_list_1)
```

However, when I break my input as shown in input_list_2 (each array matching the number of processors) and pass input_list_2[0] and input_list_2[1] as individual arguments, I find the return from the function is more predictable and matches what I expect.

Is there a way to pass the **input_list_2** as the argument and do some type of iteration? I've tried everything I can find related to iterables - imap, map_async, starmap.

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
input_list_2=[('string1','string2'),('string3','string4')]
results=pool.map(somefunction, input_list_2)
```

Comment: `somefuction` only handles strings and not tuples. you sending each tuple to `somefunction` rather than each `string`. Don't worry about dividing your list. That's what map is for, it will not start processing string3 until either string1 or string2 is done

Answer (score 1):

You probably have something like this:

```
def somefunc(str):
   ##string specific method
   print(str.strip())

pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
input_list=['string1 ','string2 ','string3 ','string4']
pool.map(somefunction, input_list)

string1
string2
string3
string4
```

where map will send each string in an iteratble to somefunc.

However when you break up your list into two tuples:

```
input_list_2=[('string1','string2'),('string3','string4')]
```

it's sending the tuple `('string1','string2')` as an argument to `somefunc`.

if you really want to chunk them that way, your function must process a tuple.

```
def somefunc(tuple):
   ##string specific method
   for x in tuple:
      print(x.strip())


pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
input_list_2=[('string1 ','string2 '), ('string3 ','string4')]
pool.map(somefunction, input_list_2)


string1
string2
string3
string4
```